# How to refrence a custom class in pandas query

Tags: python, pandas

I want to (as part of my query) instantiate a custom class then use that in the query. In the bellow example i will use a trivial identity class that does nothing.

```
import pandas as pd

class foo:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.v = var

# this is meant to turn every row in col1 into a foo object then read the v attribute then compare it to 1. I know this is silly in this case, but it is a minimal working example.
q = '@foo(col1).v > 1'

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2]})
df.query(q)
```

When I run this I get an error that the resolver could not find 'foo'. Specifically:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/kits/miniconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/scope.py:198, in Scope.resolve(self, key, is_local)
    197 if self.has_resolvers:
--> 198     return self.resolvers[key]
    200 # if we're here that means that we have no locals and we also have
    201 # no resolvers

File ~/kits/miniconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py:982, in ChainMap.__getitem__(self, key)
    981         pass
--> 982 return self.__missing__(key)

File ~/kits/miniconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py:974, in ChainMap.__missing__(self, key)
    973 def __missing__(self, key):
--> 974     raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'foo'
```

I also tried passing this to the query function using the local or global dict arguments, but both gave me the same answer.

I expected the query to properly instantiate inline and then evaluate the boolean.

Comment: I think `.query()` will evaluate only `@foo`, but not `@foo()`. Maybe you should create a new column `foo(var)` before using query an then `@` that column.

Comment: Can you modify class `foo` by adding other methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other similar option, create function `get_foo(var)` and call it:

```py
import pandas as pd


class foo:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.v = var


def get_foo(var):
    return foo(var)

q = "@get_foo(col1).v > 1"
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2]})

x = df.query(q)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   col1
1     2
```

Comment: This worked thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think that using apply would be preferable (and for sure more clear) in this scenario:

```
def check_with_foo(x):
  foo_obj = foo(x)
  return foo_obj.v > 1

df['col1'].apply(check_with_foo)
```

Comment: In this particular scenario it would be. But the code in the query can be arbitrary, and is being provided by a previous tool that translates user input into something the query function can accept.

Answer (score 0):

Via applying `foo` class [call](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__)able:

```
foo_call = foo.__call__
q = '@foo_call(col1).v > 1'

print(df.query(q))
```

---

```
   col1
1     2
```